# Extracting the StatusDescription from a text file using Python

Tags: python, nlp, log-analysis

I have a sample text file. I want to extract the StatusDescription for each line and incase its not available, i want it to return a null i.e

Line1 StatusDescription=Null

Line2 StatusDescription=Success

The sample text file:

[23-Oct-2019] [12:14:49:150] [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '7' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] [22368936] [172.30.26.90][c84283f4-5a3d-4559-b8d1-6ae2bdfc6075][com.intellectdesign.iportal.as.integrator.host.GenericCommunicator][EXIT] {Leaving the sendToHostEx method...}

[23-Oct-2019] [12:14:49:150] [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '7' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] [22368936] [172.30.26.90][c84283f4-5a3d-4559-b8d1-6ae2bdfc6075][com.intellectdesign.digitalface.formatter.CoopCardSummmaryFormatter][ERROR] {hdr_Tran_Id=COOP_CARD_DETAILS~*hdr_Ref_No=1~*res_Status=00000~*CorrelationID=AAAAAD7B5619~*MessageID=AAAAAD7B5619~*StatusCode=S_001~*StatusDescription=Success~*StatusDescriptionKey=en-US}

Comment: I'm sorry, but could you post what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work in your case:

```
import re

def find_substring(line):
    try:
        result = re.search('StatusDescription=(.*)~', line)
        return result.group(1)
    except:
        return "Null"

with open('text.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        status_description = find_substring(line)
        print(status_description)
```